# QML Set ExclusiveGroup to RadioButton in ListView programatically

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Good day

I'm trying to create a dynamic listview that contains RadioButton control.
I want to have 4 rows and each row would contain 4 radiobuttons and the buttons on each row to belong to one ExclusiveGroup

I've tried setting the ExclusiveGroup directly when create the ListElement but its giving an error

```
ExclusiveGroup {id: eg1}
ExclusiveGroup {id: eg2}
ExclusiveGroup {id: eg3}

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: myModel
    delegate: RowLayout {
        //property ExclusiveGroup eg: null
        spacing: 5
        RadioButton {
            id: r1
            text: option_1
            //exclusiveGroup: eg
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r2
            text: option_2
            //exclusiveGroup: eg
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r3
            text: option_3
            //exclusiveGroup: eg
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r4
            text: option_4
            //exclusiveGroup: eg
        }
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement {option_1: "8"; option_2: "9"; option_3: "37"; option_4: "27"}//; eg: eg1}
    ListElement {option_1: "12"; option_2: "15"; option_3: "16"; option_4: "17"} //; eg: eg2);
    ListElement {option_1: "1936"; option_2: "1938"; option_3: "1939"; option_4: "1940"} //; eg: eg3);
}
```

if I add the part eg:eg1 in `ListElement` then it will give an error

```
ListElement: cannot use script for property value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the buttons in each row to be exclusive you can make it part of the delegate:

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement {option_1: "8"; option_2: "9"; option_3: "37"; option_4: "27"}
    ListElement {option_1: "12"; option_2: "15"; option_3: "16"; option_4: "17"}
    ListElement {option_1: "1936"; option_2: "1938"; option_3: "1939"; option_4: "1940"}
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: myModel
    delegate: RowLayout {
        ExclusiveGroup { id: group } // <---
        spacing: 5
        RadioButton {
            id: r1
            text: option_1
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r2
            text: option_2
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r3
            text: option_3
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
        RadioButton {
            id: r4
            text: option_4
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of this approach as well, but was away to write it down, but  I guess you thought of it before me as well :)